# How to create a multi-dimensional softmax output in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

I came across this research paper released by YouTube, on how they use deep learning neural networks for recommendations. It's located here: https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45530.pdf

In the paper, the candidate generation neural network model outputs a softmax with 256 dimensions, which acts as an "output embedding" of each of the 1M video classes.

How is this possible to implement in Tensorflow, for example? Isn't softmax supposed to be only 1-Dimensional. If the model outputs an "embedding" like this, as they say it does, how would the training data's labels be formatted as 256-dimensional? In other words, how do they compute the 256-dimensional vector for each of the videos in their training dataset?

Also, is it possible to create an output embedding layer when the labels in the training dataset are one-hot encodings of a particular class. In other words, can the output layer automatically learn embeddings for the output class?

Thank you so much for your time and help, guys!

**Update:**
The part of the paper that discusses this on page 4, Section 3.5 (the first few lines)

Comment: I did not read about how they get a 256-D embedding but applying softmax to that should not be a problem. You can just use softmax activation along the rows axis of the matrix. Then softmax will be applied to each row of 256-D.

Comment: Actually it does say so in the paper. Check out page 4, section 3.5. So, how do we create a final layer that not only has a softmax activation but also produces a 256-dimensional vector for each of the 1M classes (which are videos in this case)? Thanks!